# How to get eos.js file in one of Dawn4.x versions?

Tags: dawn-4.1

How to get eos.js file in one of Dawn4.x versions?

In Dawn 3 one needed to run "npm install eosjs" and then the file was in the path \node_modules\eosjs\dist

I run the command and as well Dawn 4.0 "npm install eosjs@dawn4", but there is no dist folder within eosjs folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. So in order to have a file one needs to run as well:

```
git clone https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs.git
cd eosjs
npm install
npm run build_browser
```

// builds: ./dist/eos.js

The fact is that it does not work on Windows. If you try better run on Linux